# android studio background behind TextView

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to achieve something like this in Android Studio:

[image]

I don't want the background shape to be as the TextView size, I want it half the size just like the above image. This is what I tried to do:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:bottom="30dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#f3f3f3" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="20dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#FFC107" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

not exactly what I wanted. how can I do it like in the image above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

define in a `res/drawable` new file called `double_color.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/shape_rectangle">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/green" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="-10dp" android:right="-10dp" android:left="-10dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="10dp"
                android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Than define a new style in `res/values` as:

```
<style name="TexViewStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/double_color</item>
</style>
```

And last add style to your textView:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Full name"
    style="@style/TexViewStyle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Will be like this:

[image]

Comment: Great. I tried only adding the xml file and it works without adding the style, what would the style add in this case? also is there a way to make the background width more than the text itself?

Comment: Style is just a way to clean code and reuse it away in the code. So to do the background width more tha the text size you could use         android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"

Comment: Flag the answer if it's all ok and correct. And thanks